# Google Custom Search JSON API quota and billing

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api, google-custom-search, google-search-api

I'm just deciding between GSS (Google Site Search) and CSE (Custom Search Engine) with JSON API. But I'm a little bit confused about JSON API billing.

My approved start budget is 100$ per year which allows 20 000 queries/year in GSS but how many queries will I get in JSON API and how I must set quota to not exceed the budget?

**I have opinion how google makes billing:**

> Price of 1 query is 0.005$ = 5$ / 1000 queries => https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview#pricing

Google adds day queries (over 100 free) and then create billing for month. So my quota has to be set to 154 (100 free + 54):

> 54 queries per day * 31 days * 12 months = 20 088 queries * 0.005$ = 100,44$ which is maximum I will pay (lesser maybe).

Am I right? Or google makes billing in different way?